# Let $A$, $B$ be subsets of $S^n, n≥2$. Show that if $A$ and $B$ are closed, disjoint, and neither separates $S^n$, then...

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $A,B$ be subset of $S^n$, $n\geq 2$. Show that if $A$ and $B$ are closed, disjoint, and neither separates $S^n$, then $A\cup B$ does not separate $S^n$.

I've thought to do it by contradiction and use the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequences, but really I have some doubts, so the appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Did you try to cover $S^n$ by the complements of $A$ and $B$, and write down the last portion of the Mayer-Vietoris long exact sequence? I think the solution along this way is pretty straightforward...

Comment: @AlexanderShamov: What it means that a subset separates $S^n$?

Comment: @Seirios: It means that its complement is not connected, which is detected by 0-th homology.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U = S^n\setminus A$ and $V = S^n\setminus B$ then by hypothesis $U$ and $V$ cover $S^n$ so we can apply Mayer-Vietoris:
$$ H_1(S^n) \overset{\partial_*}\longrightarrow H_0(U\cap V) \overset{(i_*,j_*)}{\longrightarrow} H_0(U)\oplus H_0(V) \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} H_0(S^n) \longrightarrow 0 $$
If we assume that $n\geq 2$ then $H_1(S^n) = \{0\}$, because neither $A$ or $B$ separate $S^n$ we have that $H_0(U) = H_0(V) = \{0\}$ and the sequence is exact so we must have that $H_0(U\cap V) = \{0\}$ i.e.  $A\cup B$ does not separate $S^n$.

Comment: You probably should indicate you are using reduced homology.

Comment: I don´t think I'm using reduced homology in any part, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is for the unreduced case.

Comment: $H_0$ of a connected space is $\mathbb Z$ not $0$.